# Step-up converter current limit 2A

Tags: step-up

In the specification for the step-up booster is max. **output** current limit 2 A (or any other value based on the specific booster). Does this limit apply for the whole range of supported voltage or for the lowest voltage?

Comment: **Does this limit apply for the whole range of supported voltage or for the lowest voltage?** are you saying about the input of the step up booster.( Input voltage range for the converter)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unanswerable without the datasheet.

Comment: @winny I've seen many converters, all of them have the max output current specified (at some specific value). But not at specific voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the specifications in the datasheet. If the booster came without a datasheet, then you're on your own, and you'll have to measure it.

One of the limitations of a step-up booster is the maximum input current. If you want to achieve a high output voltage with a low input voltage (a high boost ratio), the input current would be many times the output current. Under these conditions, it would be reasonable for a general purpose booster to produce a lower output current than it could with a lower boost ratio. With luck, a booster that does this would safely limit the output to maintain the input current within bounds.

To use some numbers. Consider running the device from (say) 5v to generate either 6v or 24v. The maximum output current of 2A will occur at the lowest output voltage, 6v. With the same input current, the output will only be 500mA at 24v. Now as a manufacturer, do you limit the output over the entire range to 500mA, or do you allow the more useful behaviour of letting the output current rise at lower output voltages?

Comment: Specification in the datasheet talks about OUPUT current thought, that is whay I am confused.

Comment: have you thought about posting a link tot he datasheet, so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: As the datasheet is not in english, I have not. But I will try to find another similar.

Comment: But look here: https://www.ebay.com/itm/MT3608-DC-DC-Step-Up-Boost-Converter-Power-Supply-Module-2V-24V-to-5V-28V-2A/312279747003 Max output current is specified as well. (not a spec though)

Comment: which part of 'max' don't you understand? The current will not exceed that, but could be rather less. You may rest assured that the current is quoted under the best conditions of input and output voltage. Under more challanging constions of boost ratio, it will be less.

Comment: As I have asked: "Does this limit apply for the whole range of supported  voltage or for the lowest voltage?" I will try to ask another way. Why is the limit expressed in current (A), not in power (W).

Comment: because it's sold on eBay. The poor unsuspecting buyer thinks 'ooh, 28v at 2A, wow, 56 watts!, I gotta get me one of these hench supplies'. Nope, you'll probably get 2A output at mid volts, with a boost ratio near 1, probably rather less if you deviate from those conditions. Here's a [datasheet for the IC probably used on the board](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf). I've not read it yet, but will in the next hour. It might make interesting reading. 4A switch current limit leaps out, that limits input current to less, if the inductor used doesn't.

Comment: As I've written before, I do have specs from certified store (but you cannot read czech I guess) and the information is the same there (max output 2A). But still thanks for answers.

Comment: You'll notice the efficiency curves only go up to 800mA for 5v to 12v, and to 1.7A for 13 to 18v (very low boost ratio). The problem is the input current in the switch and the inductor. We don't know what the saturation current of the inductor used on board is. That said, it's a very tasty module, icstation.com is knocking them out for 69c at the moment. I'd have to pay that for an inductor, and they're supplying a PCB with it all on, how the costs work is beyond me. So it's good, but it's limited by input current. Don't feel bad, we all get too excited at eBay cost/performance at times.

Comment: @Divisadero I've added another paragraph with a justification of sorts why the device is specified at the optimistic rather than the pessimistic end.